# Logging Penetration Test - What do you use?

Tags: penetration-test, logging

When performing a penetration test its obviously important to keep a record of what you did. This is important both to be able to replay an attack for demonstration purposes as well as for auditing purposes.

What tool is the most useful in logging this information. Currently, I use a mixture of one-note, word and handwritten notes.

What do you use?

Comment: This is not the best format for a question here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure software recommendations are on-topic here, and you'll only get opinion based answers, but my favorite tool is [Infobyte's Faraday](http://www.infobyte.com.ar/faraday.html). It allows me to upload scan results, check off compromised systems, view all the data in beautiful graphs, and even export this data into a usable report.

**Mods:** If you feel this answer is inappropriate, please delete or let me know and I'll take it down. Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Infobyte in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I like using KeepNote. it allows me to keep track (i.e. time when i started a scan etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Information Security. While useful, this answer should either be edited to add more detail describing pros/cons or added as a comment to the question once you have sufficient reputation.